# How do I check whether I have jquery-ui running in my rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

This might sound like a very stupid question(and maybe it is) but I have reason to believe jquery-ui is not running properly on my rails app even though my understanding was that it was installed by the previous developer. Is there a quick way to check that it is properly installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Chrome, (or Firefox with firebug), you can open up your console (ctrl-shift-i) and click on your resources tab.  You should find it there under one of the scripts folder 'jquery-ui.js'

Alternatively, you can ask if one of the methods defined in jquery-ui is undefined, such as

typeof $.removeUniqueId  == 'undefined'